# JAXB dynamic annotations with same object

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, annotations

I have to map XML<->Java object and I use JAXB for marshalling and unmarshalling. It's great.
Now I have a problem: xml tags can be in different languages

Example (with only 2 languages):

English version:

```
<root>
   <elementA/>
   <elementB/>
   <elementC/>
</root>
```

Italian version:

```
<radice>
   <elementoA/>
   <elementoB/>
   <elementoC/>
</radice>
```

The question is: how manage more languages, so more xml sources with same structure but different element name, with one java object?
Is there a way to change annotations dynamically?

Goal is to have one single object, set its language, then marshall and unmarshall easily.

Interfaces or more objects are not solutions because objects involved for every language are not easy as the example but are hundreds often nested each other.

Comment: I have never seen someone want to localize XML element names.

Comment: Did you explore a possible approach of applying XSL transformation to resulting XML?

Comment: The XML definition should be defined in an universal language. Otherwise split your problem in two parts: 1) Convert to English version 2) process the data.

Comment: The same is valid for me: xml tags localization is very stupid but this is what I have in input and what customer is expecting in output. This is an international standard for particular information exchange, and yes, it's thinked by a dumber but I have not the power to change it :-)

Comment: xsl and/or conversion are not the best solutions because all is in real time and I manage thousands of requests and responses every seconds. Someone can send in a language, someother in another...

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to define an interface (or base class) for each element. You will have an XSD that defines every element in every language. You will use bindings to have the jaxb-generated classes implement (or extend) the appropriate interface (or base class). Then your business logic can deal with the interfaces. I am sure there are lots of gotchas that I am not thinking of right now, which is why I am commenting rather than answering.

Comment: Easiest way would be with dynamic annotations, but it seems that it doesn't exists.

Comment: So, After all, the best suggestion and even the pragmatic one is to manage jaxb objects for a base language and simply translate tags and attributes before and after marshalling and unmarshalling.

Comment: @stell Another option is to try to customize `javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter` so that it would localize tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very draft how it can be done with custom `XMLStreamWriter`. In these example two Maven dependencies are required (using Java 7; with Java 8 the code could be much simpler):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.dev.stax-utils</groupId>
        <artifactId>stax-utils</artifactId>
        <version>20070216</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>19.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

And here is the snippet doing the work:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = ROOT)
public static class Root {
    static final String ROOT = "root";
    static final String ELEMENT_A = "elementA";

    @XmlElement(name = ELEMENT_A)
    public Element element_a;
    public static class Element {}
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Root root = new Root();
    root.element_a = new Root.Element();

    final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);
    final Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

    final XMLOutputFactory outputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();
    final XMLStreamWriter writer = outputFactory.createXMLStreamWriter(System.out);
    final LocalizingXmlStreamWriter localizingWriter = new LocalizingXmlStreamWriter(writer, Locale.ENGLISH);
    marshaller.marshal(root, localizingWriter);
}

static class LocalizingXmlStreamWriter extends javanet.staxutils.IndentingXMLStreamWriter {
    final static Map<String, ImmutableMap<String, String>> localizations = Maps.toMap(
        Arrays.asList(Locale.ENGLISH.getLanguage(), Locale.ITALIAN.getLanguage()),
        new Function<String, ImmutableMap<String, String>>() {
            @Override
            public ImmutableMap<String, String> apply(String lang) {
                if (Locale.ENGLISH.getLanguage().equals(lang)) {
                    return Maps.toMap(Arrays.asList(ROOT, ELEMENT_A),
                        Functions.<String>identity());
                }
                else if (Locale.ITALIAN.getLanguage().equals(lang)) {
                    return Maps.toMap(Arrays.asList(ROOT, ELEMENT_A),
                        new Function<String, String>() {
                            @Override
                            public String apply(String tag) {
                                switch (tag) {
                                    case ROOT:
                                        return "radice";
                                    case ELEMENT_A:
                                        return "elementoA";
                                    default:
                                        return tag;
                                }
                            }
                        });
                }
                else throw new IllegalStateException();
            }
        }
    );

    private final ImmutableMap<String, String> localization;

    public LocalizingXmlStreamWriter(XMLStreamWriter writer, Locale locale) {
        super(writer);
        final String language = locale.getLanguage();
        localization = localizations.get(language);
        Preconditions.checkArgument(localization != null, 
            "not supported language %s", language);
    }

    @Override
    public void writeStartElement(String prefix, String localName, String namespaceURI) 
        throws XMLStreamException 
    {
        final String localizedTag = localization.get(localName);
        super.writeStartElement(prefix, localizedTag, namespaceURI);
    }
}
```